# Regarding angular js directives usage

Tags: angularjs

i am learning angular so when reading article then some time getting stuck to understand the output. here i confusion of render html output.

code taken from http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_directive

```
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" w3-test-directive></div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive("w3TestDirective", function() {
    return {
        template : "I was made in a directive constructor!"
    };
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

when the above code runs then output as follows

```
<div w3-test-directive="" ng-app="myApp" class="ng-scope">I was made in a directive constructor!</div>
```

my question is why the directive's template text gets added within start and end div tag ?`

why this attribute is blank `w3-test-directive="" in div ?`

this text `I was made in a directive constructor!` could have added in the attribute of `w3-test-directive` so the html output may look like

```
<div w3-test-directive="I was made in a directive constructor!" ng-app="myApp" class="ng-scope"></div>
```

please help me to understand why the directive's template text gets added within start and end div tag ?` thanks

Comment: Where did you expect it to be added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you use directives depends on the 'restrict' property.

If you add restrict: 'E', then you can use it as a element, ex:

```
<foo></foo>
```

If you do restrict: 'A', now its:

```
 <div foo></div>
```

More info:

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-i-the-fundamentals

Example:

```
angular.module('moduleName')
    .directive('foo', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA', //E = element, A = attribute, C = class, M = comment         
        template: 'Foo'
    }
});
```

Comment: you should post the html output too if we use restrict: 'EA'.

Comment: When the directive is used as the attribute, it will always be like directive-name="". Not adding restrict will make it same as 'EACM'. If you want to confirm, inspect the page, select Edit as HTML on the tag where directive is applied, you will find =""

Answer (score 0):

A directive renders its template *within* the element upon which it is declared. The `w3-test-directive` directive is being declared (as an attribute) on your `div` element:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" w3-test-directive></div>
```

It will therefore render your template within that element's opening and closing tags, and won't (by default) affect anything higher in the DOM tree.

Also, about valueless attributes - they don't need values. For example, the `disabled` or `async` attributes do not normally have values. That a particular attribute is merely *present* is enough, in many cases. In Angular, the presence of a directive, declared as an attribute, is often all that is needed. If you provide values, they will be interpreted as references to model data (handled by the your scope declaration within the directive definition).

Answer (score 0):

The `template` or the content from `templateURL` is always inserted between the enclosing tags on which the directive is used. Hence the `template` text added inside the div tags. This happen because untill it gets to html, it will never be displayed.

`w3-test-directive=""` : this is because of the fact that this as a attribute has no value. Since it not a known attribute in html, it has no default value, so it will be parsed like this.

I have added an example where i am using the same directive as an element tag instead of using it as a attribute

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp">
<w3-test-directive></w3-test-directive>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive("w3TestDirective", function() {
    return {
        template : "I was made in a directive constructor!"
    };
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if i want my output should be like this `<div w3-test-directive="I was made in a directive constructor!" ng-app="myApp" class="ng-scope"></div>` then what to change in directive code ?

Comment: Can you provide a use case, It will be easy to create an appropriate example

Comment: the content of the template will always be displayed with in the containing element tag. howerver, if you want to pass any additional data you can use  additional attributes. Read more at  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_custom_directives.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
why this attribute is blank w3-test-directive="" in div ?

blank space is because it show that attributes as Html5 compliance no html5 errors or warnings. same as if we write disable or readonly property.

ng-directives have menu types to declare for example :

<div ng-app="myApp" w3-test-directive></div>

above example of 'A' means Attribute it can be write as follows:

following example with 'E' Element 
<div ng-app="myApp">
 <w3-test-directive></w3-test-directive>
</div>


following example with 'C' Class 

    <div ng-app="myApp">
     <span class='w3-test-directive'></span>
    </div>


for more info please refer following link:

[angular directives][1]


  [1]: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive
```